# opencv Unable to record video from camera to a file

Tags: opencv

i am trying capture a video from webcam. But i am always getting a 441 byte size file getting created.

Also in console there is error coming
`OpenCVCMD[37317:1478193] GetDYLDEntryPointWithImage(/System/Library/Frameworks/AppKit.framework/Versions/Current/AppKit,_NSCreateAppKitServicesMenu) failed.`

Code Snippet

```
void demoVideoMaker() {

//Camera Input
VideoCapture cap(0);
vidoFeed = &cap;

namedWindow("VIDEO", WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);

//Determine the size of inputFeed
Size inpFeedSize = Size((int) cap.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH),    // Acquire input size
              (int) cap.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT));
cout<<"Input Feed Size: "<<inpFeedSize<<endl;


VideoWriter outputVideo;
char fName[] = "capturedVid.avi";
outputVideo.open(fName, CV_FOURCC('P','I','M','1'), 20, inpFeedSize, true);

if (!outputVideo.isOpened()) {
    cout<<"Failed to write Video"<<endl;
}

//Event Loop
Mat frame;
bool recordingOn = false;
while(1){
    //Process user input if any
    char ch = char(waitKey(10));
    if (ch == 'q') {
        break;
    }if (ch == 'r') {
        recordingOn = !recordingOn;
    }

    //Move to next frame
    (*vidoFeed)>>frame;
    if (frame.empty()) {
        printf("\nEmpty Frame encountered");
    }else {
        imshow("VIDEO", frame);

        if(recordingOn) {
            cout<<".";
            outputVideo.write(frame);
        }
    }
 }
}
```

I am using opencv2.4, XCode 8.2 on mac OS Sierra 10.12.1
Tried changing the codec, fps, but nothing helped. I was assuming this would be a straight forward task but got stuck here. Please help.

Comment: Have you tried FOURCC 'MJPG'?  For OpenCV 2.4, it works well on Linux (where I have used it a lot) and Windows (as far as I recall).

Comment: @UlrichStern, tried with MJPG also, but not working.

Comment: @UlrichStern did you solve the problem yet, cause I am facing the same problem

Comment: @UlrichStern, no didn't find a solution to that. I am saving frames now.